# Julia PyCall difficulties in running modules of Music21

Tags: python, julia, python-import, music21

I am a beginner having difficulties using Julia's PyCall to interface with the MIT Python music module music21.

According to Music21’s website, in order to display a short melody in musical notation one would type this in Python:

```
converter.parse("tinynotation: 3/4 c4 d8 f g16 a g f#").show()
```

Here is what I did to try and execute this code in Julia:

I first initialized music21, which seemed to work:

```
@pyimport music21
music21: Certain music21 functions might need these optional packages: matplotlib, scipy; if you run into errors, install them by following the instructions at http://mit.edu/music21/doc/installing/installAdditional.html
```

Then I tried to recreate the above Python example in Julia by typing:

converter.parse("tinynotation: 3/4 c4 d8 f g16 a g f#").show()

```
I received this error:
ERROR: UndefVarError: converter not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:235
```

**UPDATE 1**
According to rickhg12hs's suggestion, I attempted music21.converter.parse("tinynotation: 3/4 c4 d8 f g16 a g f#").show().

Now I am getting this error message on 'Parse': ERROR: type PyObject has no field parse Stacktrace: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28553722/pyplot-error-in-julia-type-pyobject-has-no-field-set-yscale) eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:235

It seems like an improvement as it is now crashing a little later in the code chain, at 'Parse' instead of 'Converter'.

**UPDATE 2 - FIXED**
This issue has to do with [dot overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28553722/pyplot-error-in-julia-type-pyobject-has-no-field-set-yscale).
Based on this link, I tried modifying my code to look like this:

```
music21.converter[:parse]("tinynotation: 3/4 c4 d8 f g16 a g f#")[:show]()
```

but now I get this error

```
FSPathMakeRef(/Applications/MuseScore 2.app/Contents/MacOS/mscore) failed with error -43.
```

I discovered that the last thing I had to do was to download MuseScore and now the problem is fixed!

See @crstnbr's answer for more context on the ugliness of this solution and imminent fixes.

Many thanks!
Nakul

Comment: I've never used this Python package (and you would cringe at my guitar playing), but I'm wondering what happens if you try `music21.converter.parse("tinynotation: 3/4 c4 d8 f g16 a g f#").show()`.

Comment: This is my first time using PyCall. Your suggestion might have improved the scenario a little bit. Now I am getting this error message on 'Parse': ERROR: type PyObject has no field parse
Stacktrace:
 [1] eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:235

Comment: Would you edit your question to include this new information?  It helps everyone who may look at this issue later.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just did.

Comment: @crstnbr shows the (temporarily ugly) way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have the package installed (I'll test it in a second) but the following should work:

```
@pyimport music21 as m
m.converter[:parse]("tinynotation: 3/4 c4 d8 f g16 a g f#")[:show]()
```

Note that the arguably ugly (but systematic) `[:fieldname]` access will go away sometime soon in Julia 1.0 after my [Pull request](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl/pull/517) here gets merged. The reason for this syntax is that Julia didn't allow to override the `.` access functionality. This, fortunately, changed in Julia 1.0.

Comment: I only installed `music21`, but this works for me `music21.converter[:parse]("tinynotation: 3/4 c4 d8 f g16 a g f#")[:show]("text")`

Comment: Thank you very much! I just independently arrived at the code solution, but your added context is very useful and interesting. I'm excited to not have to include those [:]'s once your pull request gets merged.

Comment: Ok, guess I was to slow in installing the package :)

Comment: Hey @crstnbr , Do you know if it's possible for me to implement your pull request without recompiling Julia? If not, is there a resource pointing to a straightforward way of recompiling Julia with your contribution (I am new with that fort of stuff). The more I am working with PyCall, it seems like your contribution is a HUGE timesaver.

Comment: You don't need to recompile Julia as this is only a PyCall issue, which is an external package. You could dowload my fork of the package and use the PR's branch to try it out. However, I think you really shouldn't do that, but instead wait for the PR to get merged, as the implementation isn't completed yet and might contain bugs.

Comment: I'll work on the PR on the weekend, so maybe we can already merge it next week. It will be up to Steven (the package owner).

Comment: I appreciate it @crsnbr. I still need to upgrade to Julia 1.0 (I'm still using 0.6) before I can experience the enhanced . access functionality anyway. I'll stay tuned!